# Reset Form Javascript After 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, forms

```
< script > $(function () {
    $('#contact-form').validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                url: 'process.php',
                success: function () {
                    $('#contact-form').append("<p>Thanks! Your request has been sent.</p>");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}); < /script>

<!-- Form -->
<div id="contact-form"><form id="contact-form" action="process.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <label>
            <span>Name: (required)</span > < input type = "text"
        name = "name"
        placeholder = "Full Name"
        title = "Enter your name"
        class = "required" > < /label>
    </div > < div > < label > < span > Email: (required) < /span>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" title="Enter your email" class="required">         
        </label > < /div>
    <div>
        <label>
            <span>Telephone: (required)</span > < input type = "text"
        name = "phone"
        placeholder = "Your Telephone"
        title = "Enter your telephone"
        class = "required" > < /label>
    </div > < div > < label > < span > Website: (required) < /span>
            <input type="text" name="website" placeholder="Your Website" title="Enter your website">            
        </label > < /div>
    <div>
        <label>
            <span>Message: (required)</span > < textarea placeholder = "Include all the details you can"
        name = "message"
        type = "text"
        tabindex = "5"
        required > < /textarea>
        </label > < /div>
    <div>
        <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Send Email</button > < /div>
</form > < /div>
<!-- /Form-- >

         < /div>
</div >

< script src = "jss/scripts.js" > < /script>
```

I have this code i want to reset form after 3 seconds and make message from append "Thank! your request ... to reset him too after 3 second with form but without refreshing page. Were and how can i make that ?

Comment: you can use this after success "$('input[type=text],input[type=password]').val("");"

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **`reset()`** and **`setTimeout()`** like

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $('form').reset();  // to reset the form
}, 3000);  // 3000 represents 3 seconds
```

---

In your case,

```
success: function() {
$('#contact-form').append("<p>Thanks! Your request has been sent.</p>");
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#contact-form').reset();
    }, 3000);
}
```

**FYI:** your `form id` and `div id` are **same**. **[IDs should be UNIQUE ]**

```
<div id="contact-form"><form id="contact-form" action="process.php" method="post">
```

This is *wrong* change the *id* of *div*

Comment: @user3248759 This could be a problem, try changing `$('#contact-form')[0].reset();`

Comment: <script>
$(function(){
$('#contact-form').validate({
submitHandler: function(form) {
$(form).ajaxSubmit({
  url: 'process.php',
success: function() {
$('#contact-form').append("<p>Thanks! Your request has been sent.</p>");
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
    }, 3000);
}
});}
});
});
</script>  but nothing

Comment: @user3248759 Is your ajax working? are you able to see the message `Thanks! Your request has been sent`

Comment: @user3248759 you form id and div id are same..[IDs should be UNIQUE ]`<div id="contact-form"><form id="contact-form" action="process.php" method="post">`  This is wrong change the id of div and check it

Comment: i changed name of <div id in contact-forms but the message not appear

Comment: verify now, you will see <div id="contact-forms"> but when  click on send email the message "thank ..." wil not appear

Comment: @user3248759 it is working for me.  The `thank..` message I can see and also the after 2 seconds the form is resetting

Answer (score 0):

Just add in `success`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#contact-form').reset();
}, 3000);
```

So:

```
$(form).ajaxSubmit({
  url: 'process.php',
  success: function() {
    $('#contact-form').append("<p>Thanks! Your request has been sent.</p>");

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#contact-form').reset();
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to  use `Form.reset();` .it will reset your form by 3 secs.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
}, 3000);
```

I have prepared a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HDf5B/) here.You can follow it..

Comment: Have you look at the demo